# Java LinkedList -- Retrieving the index of an Object

Tags: java, linked-list

I guess this question that would have already been asked here. I searched but could not find anything similar. So here goes --
I have a custom data object `Method` and `Method` is as follows --

```
public Class Method {
List<String> inputParameters;
String resultVariableName;
}
```

Now i have a `LinkedList<Method>` which acts as a repository of `Method` objects.

Given a `Method` object is there a way in which the correct index of the `Method` object can be concretely determined.
My question arises from the face that `LinkedList` class has an `indexOf` routine but this routine returns the first occurrence of the object but then there is no given that 2 copies of `Method` object can not reside in the `LinkedList`(right ?)
Would tagging every `Method` object as I add it to the `LinkedList` solve my purpose and if so is there an ideal way to do it ?

EDIT :
Explaining my use case a little further.
My code basically reads a Velocity template top-down and creates `Method` objects. One `Method` object is created for every velocity routine encountered.
This explains why the same element can be stored at multiple indices in the `LinkedList` as there is no real restriction on how many number of time a `Velocity` routine is called or the inputs/results provided to the `Velocity` routine.

Now, i have  a UI component, one `JButton` per `Method` object reference in the `LinkedList<Method>` by using which the user can click and edit the `Method` object.

Thus i need to know which exact `Method` object reference to edit in the event that same elements reside twice or more number of times in the `LinkedList<Method>`

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand you right. You like to save the index of (an object in the list) in the object? And now, if you add it a second time? Have a list of indexes in the object, or prevent a second add operation? Maybe you're looking for a Set, where every object can only be added once.

Comment: What is the purpose of adding same object twice to the list?

Comment: @All Edited to explain my use case further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by the "correct" index in the first place? If the linked list can contain the same element twice or more (and be careful here - the list will only contain a *reference* to a `Method` object, not the object itself) then which index would be "correct" in your view?

Of course you can just iterate over the linked list yourself and return *all* indexes at which a given `Method` reference occurs, but it's not clear what you're trying to do with it.

Note that indexes aren't often used with linked lists to start with, as obtaining the element *at* a given index is an O(n) operation.

Comment: Thanks ! Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Jon's answers always makes sense... if they don't make sense then "sense" is wrong, not Jon.  Anyway if you only want a single instance of any given Method but order/index is important you should use a LinkedHashMap, if you want multiple instances and order/index  is important iterate over your linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates are allowed in LinkedList's.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList does not avoid duplicates, it may have more than one copy.

You can put a logic to avoid multiple instances, extend the linkedlist class and override the add function to check if Method object already exists.

OR

If you want to get all instances of the Method object, you can use a ListIterator and collect all instances of it, and return this collection as a result.

Answer (score 0):

*"there is not given  2 copies of Method object can not reside in the LinkedList"*, if this is a scenario, how will you identify which object to retrieve??

In this case, I would suggest you to use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), where you can use a Identifier as a key to uniquely identify a `Method's` object.